# Please make the difference between this site and rus.stackexchange.com explicit

Tags: support

Recently I read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta) and looked onto a list of sites and... suddenly "Russian" and "Русский язык" on different URIs and each having very similar description.

How do I know where I want to ask my question? Is the difference that on one site all communications must be in English and on the second site they must be in Russian or is there any other difference? I don't see hints so far.

Answer (score 2):

This happened for historical reasons and the shortest answer would be - if you have an question in English, russian.stackexchange.com is definitely what you are looking for. If your question is in Russian it's more tricky however that doesn't mean the question in Russian does not belong to russian.stackexchange.com as well.

In short, russian.stackexchange.com came into existence as a result of standard area51-proposal, while the second belongs to the Stackexchange community due to acquisition of a bunch of Russian-language clones of Stackexchange.